# MarionetteJS - code organization

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, single-page-application, code-organization

I am starting a new project with the idea of moving some logic to client side.
I was looking in Backbone, and later in Marionette. Looks like it is a very good library which extends backbone to make it easier to create an application.

However, I couldn't find in any place a good document explaining the architecture and philosophy behind modules in Marionette.

My question is, although it is quite wide, how should I organize my code? What is the idea behind **Module**? What should it represent?

My reference is the [MarionetteJS TODO example](http://todomvc.com/labs/architecture-examples/backbone_marionette/).

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I do not want to write many texts I will just demonstrate two folders structures I like.

### Group by independent modules (<3)

```
src
   application
        router.js  // router here or for each module
        main.js    // app entry point
   profile
        collections
        models
        views
        templates
        profile.js // module entry point
   news
        collections
        models
        views
        templates
        news       // module entry point
```

### Group by Backbone types

```
src
   collections
         profile
         news
   models
         profile
         news
   modules
         profile.js // module entry point
         news.js    // module entry point
   views
         profile
         news
   templates
         profile
         news
   router.js       // router
   main.js         // app entry point
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Short and clean.... what about 'module'? In the example I mentioned I see that a module binds different components (as ItemView, ListView) and also it is possible to create a sub-module. But I couldn't figure out what is the exact definition of it. Any hint for this?

Comment: I would suggest do not use sub-modules. They should be independent and this allows to make them more reusable. If your module is too big - it's time to divide it to few independent modules.

Comment: Can you please explain what 'module' stands for? And why should I use a module?

Comment: "This is useful for creating modular, encapsulated applications that are split apart in to multiple files." https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.application.module.md